# Splitting a string and returning the pieces

Tags: string, rust

How would I create a String inside a function, split it and return its contents? The code below fails because the lifetime of variable `s` ends at the end of function `f`, but the returned `Obj` lasts beyond that. I was hoping that moving `holder` into the `Obj` would tie its lifetime to `'a` but that doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
struct Obj<'a> {
    holder : String,
    p1 : &'a str,
    p2 : &'a str,
    p3 : &'a str
}

fn f<'a>() -> Obj<'a> {
    //let slice = "a,b,c";
    let s : String = from_str("a,b,c").unwrap();
    let slice = s.as_slice();
    let pieces : Vec<&'a str> = slice.split_str(",").collect();

    Obj {
        holder : s,
        p1: pieces[0],
        p2: pieces[1],
        p3: pieces[2]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let obj = f();
    println!("{}", obj.p2);
}
```

Comment: You might also find value in reading an article of mine which deals with a related area, though not quite the same thing: http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html

Comment: Unrelated, but the best way to get a String from a string literal (or any &str) is to use `"literal".into_string()`, or soon `"literlal".to_owned()` - your current use of `from_str` is overly complex and will do many unnecessary checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "extend" the lifetime of something when you return it from a function; you just *can't*.

There are a few ways you can re-write this code, though:

1. Have `Obj` lazily compute the pieces.  That is, you return an `Obj` which has a method which does the same thing that `f` does.  That way, you can tie the lifetime of the pieces to the lifetime of `&self` (which will be the `Obj` instance).  In that case, `Obj` won't need the `'a` parameter.
2. Make each piece a newly-allocated `String` which owns its contents (thus avoiding the lifetime issue).  Then, it becomes `f() -> (String, String, String)`.
3. Take `s` as an argument, allowing you to tie the lifetimes of the pieces to *that*.  In that case, you'd end up with `f(s: &str) -> (&str, &str, &str)`.

In general, you cannot create something inside a function and then return references to it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `struct` that contains a borrowed pointer that refers to another member of the same `struct`. Here have two options to work around this:

- Store the start and the length of each substring, or the start and the end of each substring. You can provide methods on your struct to construct slices on demand.
- Store `String`s (convert your slices by using [`into_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrAllocating.html#tymethod.into_string)). You don't need to store the original string with this solution, but it allocates more memory on the heap.